# Is there any mock data analytic tools I can run queries upon?

Tags: google-analytics, mocking, analytics

There are many data mocking tools like mockaroo, faker.js amongst many, many others.

However, I am wondering if there is any data analytic mocking tools that allow us to run queries upon.

Our purpose is to use demo/mock analytics in a demo with clients to show them specific techniques they can do/use on web/data analytics.

I am aware of

https://www.bounteous.com/insights/2016/08/03/google-analytics-demo-account/

But are there any others?

With thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google has a demo account for this https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/6367342?hl=en